# Movie in which an astronaut continues the mission after his mission partner dies early in the mission

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to remember the title of a movie that I think I saw on DVD in which an astronaut completes the mission in spite of his partner dying early in the mission.  The astronaut who died is played by a Caucasian actor and the astronaut who completes the mission is played by an African-American actor. Part of the spacecraft is damaged and the surviving astronaut sends the deceased astronaut back to Earth in the damaged part of the spacecraft as they slingshot around the Earth.  I can't remember the actor's name or the title of the movie.

Comment: Were there any science fiction aspects to this, or was it then current tech?

Comment: I don't recall anything unusual, so I would guess that it is current tech.  I think the movie may be fairly recent and it may have gone direct to DVD, but I don't know.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Thanks for your help on this and for editing my answer to make it really great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it: The title is *[Astronaut: The Last Push](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1541123/)*.  The astronaut is played by Khary Payton.

> When a tragic accident cuts short the first manned mission to explore life on the moons of Jupiter, Michael Forrest must make the 3 year journey home to Earth in pure solitude.

### Trailer